# Android: ¿Como hacer eventos distintos al tocar un boton y al mantener presionado el mismo?

Tags: java, android, timer

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de android, donde necesito que un botón realice 2 acciones distintas en determinadas circunstancias:

1. Al tocarlo (no mantener presionado), haga el evento1.
2. Al mantener presionado por 5 segundos, haga el evento2.

En el res/layout:

```
<insat.aes.relojcontrol.ButtonInsat
                android:id="@+id/Button01"
                android:onClick="tapIniciarClase"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

En el src:

```
public void tapIniciarClase(View v)
{
    _presentadorPrincipal.solicitarMostrarVistaIdentificacion(true);
}
```

Cabe mencionar que el código no es mio, este era uno de los proyecto de alguien que lo abandono y me dejaron a cargo. Eso es todo lo relacionado al Boton que encontre en el codigo

Comment: Hola @Gonzalox2. Que has probado? Qué cçodigo tienes hasta ahora? Te da algún error? Para que veas como funciona el sitio te recomiendo que mires [tour] y pararealizar una pregunta de calidad mira [ask].

Comment: @Gonzalox2 Para entender mejor pregunta editala y muestra el codigo que tienes ya. Creando un [mcve]

Comment: Busca el evento `onLongClick`. Hay mucha documentación sobre el tema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para iniciar, en tu caso, debemos seleccionar el botón en cuestión, buscando su ID:

```
Button boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
```

Para detectar una pulsación corta sobre un elemento, se debe lanzar un listener setOnClickListener sobre el elemento, para captura el evento onClick.

```
boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onClick(View v) {
        //Pulsación corta

        return false;
    }
});
```

Para detectar una pulsación larga sobre un elemento, se debe lanzar un listener setOnLongClickListener sobre el elemento, para captura el evento onLongClick.

```
boton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        //Pulsación larga

        return false;
    }
});
```

He leido que buscas que el evento se produzca a los 5 segundos. El evento `LongClick` (si no recuerdo mal) se produce a los 3 segundos aproximadamente y este valor es inamovible (lo gestiona Android). Hay un pequeño truco para poder establecer una pulsación larga de 5 segundos, usando el evento `Touch` y comparando la diferencia de milisegundos desde que se pulsa el botón (`ACTION_DOWN`) hasta que se deja de pulsar (`ACTION_UP`):

```
long tiempoEnMS = 0;

boton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            tiempoEnMS = (Long) System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            if(((Long) System.currentTimeMillis() - tiempoEnMS) >= 5000){
                // Acción a realizar tras una pulsación de 5 segundos

                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

Muestro el código completo que yo he realizado (MCVE). Está funcionando correctamente:

```
package com.example.juan.aplicaciondeejemplo;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);

    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int color;
            View contender = v.getRootView();
            color = Color.parseColor("#A5D6A7"); // Verde
            contender.setBackgroundColor(color);
            Log.i("Gonzalox2", "*Evento 1.");
        }
    });


    boton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                tiempoEnMS = (Long) System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                if(((Long) System.currentTimeMillis() - tiempoEnMS) >= 5000){
                    // Acción a realizar tras una pulsación de 5 segundos
                    int color;
                    View contender = v.getRootView();
                    color = Color.parseColor("red"); // Rojo
                    contender.setBackgroundColor(color);

                    Log.i("Gonzalox2", "*Evento 2. Al mantener presionado por 5 segundos, haga el evento2.");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}

long tiempoEnMS = 0;
}
```

Comment: efectivamente, la ultima parte ,mas en onClickListener me ha funcionado, aunque para el onTouchListener, debo presionar una vez el botón y desde la segunda en adelante lo hace, alguna idea de porque?

Comment: Acabo de probarlo de nuevo, y el código es funcional. Está funcionando correctamente y se comporta como debería. Revisa donde estás inicializando `long tiempoEnMS = 0;` (debe de ser fuera del `onCreate`). Otra cosa no se me ocurre, el código está bien.

Comment: @Gonzalox2 He actualizado la respuesta con un códgo funcional. Pruébalo, debería de funcionarte.

Comment: funciono perfecto! ,muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada. Si te fue útil te agradecería que también marcases la respuesta como útil (dándole al tick verde de la izquierda). Un saludo.

Comment: listo, pense no podia, como no me deja valorarla, nuevamnete, muchas gracias!

Comment: No hay de qué, estamos para ayudar en la medida de lo posible :)

Answer (score 0):

No existe evento que se pueda llamar desde el layout para onLongPressed solo para click `android:onClick="metodo"`, por lo tanto la solución es:

Agregar un listener setOnTouchListener() para detectar el evento 1 al detectar `ACTION_DOWN`. y usar el mismo listener setOnTouchListener() para detectar el evento 2, detectando el tiempo que se tarda en tocarlo. Si se deja de tocar el botón antes de 5 segundos, el evento 2 debe cancelarse.

Este es un ejemplo:

```
//Declarar variable a nivel de clase para determinar si se cancela el evento que se llamaría hasta los 5 segundos. 
private boolean cancelLongClick = false;

...
...

      Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button01);

           myButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                   if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                        Log.i("Gonzalox2", "*Evento 1. Al tocarlo (no mantener presionado), haga el evento1.");
                       cancelLongClick = false;

                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if(!cancelLongClick) {
                                    Log.i("Gonzalox2", "*Evento 2. Al mantener presionado por 5 segundos, haga el evento2.");
                                }else{
                                    Log.i("Gonzalox2", "*Evento 2. Cancelado.");
                                }
                            }
                        }, 5000);


                    }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "MotionEvent.ACTION_UP");
                        //Si se deja de tocar antes de 5 segundos cancela el evento.
                        cancelLongClick = true;
                    }


                    return true;
                }
            });
```